# Sumif with arrayformula and horizontal and vertical ranges

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to essentially do a "sumif" with criteria that are in both horizontal and vertical ranges in google sheets. I found a reference that says excel can do this with arrayformulas [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/558912-sumif-index-match.html).

I think I've copied the syntax according to how arrayformulas work in gsheets, but I can't get it to work. I made a quick sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KglRPiWKT5fi669mm8psgNfFt7pz1YwbpoqMvR3Yg2A/edit#gid=0), where the "sum" column should match date in column B with Row 3 and "yes" for column L to give a result of "2" for every date, but for some reason I'm getting an error.

What's even stranger is that a perfect match of this formula on my actual dataset returns a numerical date each time... I'm sure this can be done with more intelligent index matching (which I would be fine with!) but haven't been able to get that to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You last range should exclude row 3:

```
=arrayformula(sum(if($G$3:$K$3=B4,if($L$4:$L$6="Yes",$G$4:$K$6))))
```